# Simple Drools 6 and Spring Example

Tags: java, spring, drools

I would like to use drools in my project but keep it as generic as possible. What I would like to do is that given a drools file (it's path) and a set of objects I would like to execute all the rules in the given file against the list of given objects. So far all the examples I have seen have the drool's file hard-coded in some config, is there a way to make it more generic?

Comment: Well, you can point into some directory, list it and then add it: `KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(); for (String drlFileRules : getDroolsFileRules()) { kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(drlFileRules), ResourceType.DRL); }`

Comment: I think `KnowledgeBuilder` is going to be deprecated soon in favour of KIE classes

Comment: How are you loading drools file right now?

Comment: I've been looking for a way to load the drool files but so far no luck

Comment: Look standard example: [http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e23406](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e23406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for various resources, not just DRL.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "simple/simple.drl" );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl", 
           kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
// check there have been no errors for rule setup
Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
    System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
    throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
}
KieContainer kieContainer =
    kieServices.newKieContainer( kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId() );
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: The following two lines insert and evaluate a particular object: `kieSession.insert(fact);  kieSession.fireAllRules();`

Comment: For a stateless session use the following code `StatelessKieSession kSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession(); kSession.execute(fact);`